# Modifying the' format' field in Springdoc OpenAPI Schema

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

I'm currently using Spring Boot 2.6.1 and Springdoc OpenAPI 1.7.0 in my project. In the generated OpenAPI documentation, I have a "Sortable" schema with a property "sort". The "format" field for this property is currently showing as "string :: Sorts the records according to the parameter.", but I want it just to be "string" Here's the current part of the schema:

```
{
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Sortable": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Sorts the records according to the parameter.",
                        "format": "string :: Sorts the records according to the parameter.",
                        "example": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the expected schema:

```
{
    "components": {
        "schemas": {
            "Sortable": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                    "sort": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "description": "Sorts the records according to the parameter.",
                        "format": "string",
                        "example": "date"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Java code:

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Sortable {

  @Schema(description = "Sorts the records according to the parameter.", example = "date", type = "string")
  private String sort;
}
```

How can I modify my configuration or annotations to remove the extra text in the "format" field and show it as a "string"? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `format` is an [annotation](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/generic.html#annotations) per the JSON Schema specificcation, which OpenAPI is based on. There is no registered format assertion with `string :: ...`. While this is not to say it doesn't exist *somewhere*, it's not recognized by JSON Schema or OpenAPI, by default.

> Implementations MAY still treat "format" as an assertion in addition to an annotation and attempt to validate the value's conformance to the specified semantics. The implementation MUST provide options to enable and disable such evaluation and MUST be disabled by default. Implementations SHOULD document their level of support for such validation
> https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-validation.html#section-7

Depending on the version of OpenAPI used determines which set of format values are available for use.

OAS 3.1.x allows all JSON Schema format types
[JSON Schema registered formats](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html?highlight=format#built-in-formats)

OAS 3.0.x only allows the defined types in the OAS specification.
[OpenAPI registered formats](https://spec.openapis.org/oas/v3.0.3#data-types)

---

> How can I modify my configuration or annotations to remove the extra text in the "format" field and show it as a "string"? Any help would be appreciated.

The `type` keyword defines the semantics of the property, not the `format` keyword. In your case, the `format` keyword *MAY* be deleted, but it appears like your java code has already ignored it.

Comment: Thanks for response, quick question -  is it possible to remove it remove the keyword `format` from the JSON schema?

Comment: From a validation perspective, it _shouldn't_ affect anything if you remove it

Comment: Any idea how I can remove it?

Comment: From your java code example, it doesn't appear to be defined.

Comment: Even when I define it from the schema annotation, it still shows in the JSON.

Comment: Must be some other place in your code or spring doc is adding it for some reason.